# Add [username] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App/post]

Tags: php, laravel

Iam learning Laravel and PHP, I am trying to add a post into my table by using Tinker from Artisan.

I receive these error I don't understand :

```
Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/MassAssignmentException with message 'Add [username] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App/post].'
```

In my Post.php model I have :

```
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'content'];
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That is suppose to make your insert possible already. But can you try `protected $guarded = [];` in place of `protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'content'];` ? Let me know the error that comes up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to exit tinker and run it again `php artisan tiker`, tinker doesn't track changes when it's running.

Comment: Yes but I have to wait 5 minutes before I can do it